# Video files(mp4,flv) is not playing in Linux server

Tags: java, video

I have an application, in that am uploading video files such as mp4, flv formats. The videos are playing well in the Windows.But in the Linux, its not playing, its showing that the MIME Type is not found.Does anyone know about these means kindly please guide me to sort out this problem.

Comment: Probably means the MIME types weren't set up for your server.  What server are you running?

Comment: We are running our application in Arvixe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the MIME types with the WebsitePanel.

http://blog.arvixe.com/mime-type-in-website-properties-–-websitepanel/

I don't know much about Arvixe, but that should hopefully get it working for you.

Comment: Thanks for your info.http://blog.arvixe.com/mime-type-in-website-properties-–-websitepanel/ In this link, they had given for windows hosting but we are using Linux hosting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ".htaccess" file which will allow per-directory access control to your server directory.

Create one .htaccess file with below code

**AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/webm .webm**

Upload that file in root directory.

For refrence : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

Hope it will help.

Comment: This is only for Apache servers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ Dan Goodspeed